# Inheriting from keras Model or Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, inheritance

In the [documentation][1] on subclassing `tf.keras.Model` and `tf.keras.Layer`, it seems like the former behaves exactly like the latter but has some added functionality. Yet, they seem to indicate that you will usually want to subclass `Layer` instead. Is there any disadvantage to inheriting from `Model`?

P.S.: I think this confusion is the reason why PyTorch only promotes subclassing `torch.nn.Module`.

[1]: [https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20you,yourself](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20you,yourself))%2C%0Ause%20Layer.

Comment: The torch.nn.Module primarily because it provides a powerful and flexible way to define neural network architectures. and By subclassing torch.nn.Module, ensure that your network's parameters are tracked by PyTorch's autograd system, enabling automatic computation of gradients during backpropagation.